# Type conversion issue in javascript

Tags: javascript

When i am trying to do

```
console.log("100" * null) // (1)
console.log("100" + null) // (2)
```

its giving me result "0" and "100null" respectively I just wanted to know how javascript typecasting working in this case .

Comment: + is overloaded to be concatenation if the string is first

Comment: @mplungjan: Doesn't have to be first, just *either*; `1 + "2"` and `"1" + 2` are both `"12"`.

Comment: Yes, I probably meant `" "+2+3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first cases `"100"` is converted to `100`, since `*` is a math operator that acts on Numbers.

All the operands are converted to Number

```
(+"100") * (+null) // +null = 0; 100 * 0 = 0
```

and in the second case, `+` isn't viewed as math operator, instead as concatenate operator(due to the first operand being String)

So `null` is converted to it's string representation due to the call to it's internal `ToString` method, so it's just concatenation(`"100" + "null"`)

Comment: thanks it really give me understanding.